# Competing risk regression p value vs. cumulative incidence p value

Tags: regression, competing-risks

I am using the "cmprsk" package in R to test whether risk of developing a disease is significantly different between 3 groups. I can see the crr() function produces a p value for the variables entered into the regression as well as odds ratios, however, there is also a p value for the difference between the Cumulative Incidence curves (Gray's test). Which p value should I be using to determine whether there is a significant difference between groups in a particular risk?